# Unity particle not deleting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to delete a game object (powerup) yet the particle clones itself even after I delete it. How would i be able to fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour {

    public float multiplier = 1.4f;
    public float duration = 4f;

    public GameObject pickupEffect;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
           StartCoroutine (Pickup(collision));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Pickup(Collider2D player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Power up picked up!");

        Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation;

        PlayerStats stats = player.GetComponent<PlayerStats>();
        stats.health *= multiplier;

        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);

        stats.health /= multiplier;

        Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the end of you coroutine, change `Destroy(this);` to `Destroy(gameObject);`

`Destroy(this);` destroys the `PowerUp` component. while `Destroy(gameObject);` destroys the entire tree.

---

Also `OnTriggerEnter2D` can be called several times in a row causing endless instantiations. you can add a constraint before `StartCoroutine` to prevent that.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
       if (!flag)
           StartCoroutine (Pickup(collision));
    }
}

IEnumerator Pickup(Collider2D player)
{
    flag = true;
```

Comment: ive tried destroy game object but the particle clones itself and i can still collide with it

Comment: you mean the `pickupEffect` ?

Comment: yeah thats the one!